# Создание триггера в SQL

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте. 
Имеется таблица в базе данных

```
[dbo].[Query](
    [Num] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Client] [int] NULL,
    [doer] [int] NULL,
    [DateOfQuery] [datetime] NULL,
    [Dwell] [int] NULL,
```

Мне нужно создать триггер, чтобы при добавлении новой записи дата была не больше текущей.
У меня возникла проблема с постановкой ограничения.
Только начинаю учить SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну если нужен именно триггер, тогда можно его создать, используя следующую конструкцию:

```
create trigger trigger_name
on table_name
instead of insert
as
--тут собственно и выполняете
--все необходимые операции
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам не нужен триггер, достаточно добавить constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Query](
    [Num] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Client] [int] NULL,
    [doer] [int] NULL,
    [DateOfQuery] [datetime] NULL CHECK ([DateOfQuery] <= GetDate()),
    [Dwell] [int] NULL)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я учту это.
Но к сожалению мне нужен именно триггер.

Comment: чем вызвана необходимость именно триггера?